# R read a list of items, that can be passed in filter

Tags: r, filter

Hello looking for help:

Say I have a list of the items

```
my.list <- read.csv("~/R/Work Stuff/Data/Read.csv")
```

After read.csv -
Item
1 ItemA
2 ItemB
3 ItemC

Now I want to create a new vector MPP.Item which is essentially my list of items which I want to use as a filter condition to filter other data set.

```
MPP.Item=c(my.list)

MPP %>% filter(Item %in% MPP.Item)
```

However, it is not working. If I am manually  creating it as a vector say:

```
my.list2 <- c("ItemA", "ItemB", "ItemC")
```

Works fine

Thanks for your advises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my.list` is a dataframe, extract the vector from it.

```
library(dplyr)

MPP.Item = my.list$Item

MPP %>% filter(Item %in% MPP.Item)

#Without using additional variable `MPP.Item`. 
#MPP %>% filter(Item %in% my.list$Item)
```